# can bluetooth be set as a Drive in windows?

Tags: bluetooth

i wanted to know is it possible to set a bluetooth connection as a drive in Windows. Just like a USB drive when its put into USB in PC, it gets mounted as a drive.. Can a bluetooth connection be mounted as a drive in Windows??

Comment: What do you need to do this for?

Comment: @ephilip: To transfer files, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

If both devices implement the Bluetooth [File Transfer Profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile) you can "browse, manipulate and transfer objects (files and folders) in an object store (file system) of another system"

[Hard Drive Help](http://www.hard-drive-help.com/external-hard-drive.html) says

> The bluetooth external hard drive has not caught on because the interface is too slow for transferring the kind of data you would want to put on a hard drive. The bluetooth hard drive interface is much slower than even USB 1.x. Toshiba introduced a 5GB bluetooth external hard drive but it was never much more than a curiosity.

Comment: This unfortunately depends on the Bluetooth stack being used... Broadcom software supports OBEX FTP, while Microsoft's native implementation doesn't.